# Получение результата хранимой процедуры с помощью Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Есть хранимая процедура:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_Test]
@intpparam int
AS
BEGIN

SELECT DllName FROM ComponentTable WHERE ID!=@intpparam

END
```

Возвращает множество всех DllName типа char удовлетворяющих запросу. 
Как используя Entity Framework получить всё множество?

PS: Для случая если возвращается множество int/float и т.п (например если запрашиваю ID записи). вполне отлично отрабатывает код:

```
var tmp = DC.p_Test(1);//DC-контекст базы

foreach (var t in tmp)
 {
   var n = t;
  // Do some work
 }
```

Но в случае с char (string в интерпретации Entity) этот код генерирует ошибку "Результат запроса нельзя перечислить более одного раза". 
И тем не менее даёт возможность получить первую запись следующим образом:

```
var tmp = tmp.First();
```

Но это только первая запись, и как получить остальные я не знаю....

Comment: var tmp = DC.p_Test(1).ToList();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> var tmp = DC.p_Test(1).ToList(); –  Konst 14 минут назад

Да, это решение. Как-то сразу не догадался...